# Rails scraping of price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I am developing a rails app in that I have to scrape the price from the link but unable to do so [link](http://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B00WER132G/ref=olp_page_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448947981&sr=1-12)

```
mechanize=Mechanize.new
     page = mechanize.get('url') 
     doc=page.parser
     #seller price
     puts doc.css('div.olpOffer div.a-span2 span.currencyINRFallback').text
```

Comment: On further review, It looks like they are nesting spans with the price `</span>600.00</span></span>`. However, you can still access it if you adjust your selector in `doc.css(selector).text` and extract the entire parent then just extract it from the string (i.e. looking for numbers before the `>` after the last `</span>`

Comment: What is it returning? You might have it right but just need to pull out the price. If you edit your question post and include what it is outputting, it will be very easy to help you understand how to do that.

Comment: Try `olpShippingPrice` instead of `currencyINRFallback` and show what you get... it will include it.

Comment: olpOfferPrice... sorry

Comment: That would be another valid question to ask here on stackoverflow.com. I would be happy to help you with that one too. BtW, if my answer was good for you, please consider checking it as answered. :)

Comment: I have posted that question can u plze help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price was nested in the span above.

```
mechanize=Mechanize.new
  page = mechanize.get('http://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B00WER132G/ref=olp_page_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448947981&sr=1-12') 
  doc=page.parser
  #seller price
  puts doc.css('div.olpOffer div.a-span2 span.olpOfferPrice').text
```

Per pguardiarit's comment..

```
mechanize=Mechanize.new
page = mechanize.get('http://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B00WER132G/ref=olp_page_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448947981&sr=1-12')
#seller price  
puts page.css('div.olpOffer div.a-span2 span.olpOfferPrice').text
```

Comment: Just `page.css`, there's no need to mess around with `page.parser`.